# How to make delete button and complete buttons work on ToDO List Javascript

Tags: javascript, events

I am creating a ToDo List in Javascript, and I am not sure how to get my delete/complete buttons to work. When I hit my delete button I want it to remove the `li` and when I hit the complete button I want my `li` background to change to background to `#51DF70. So far when I hit my delete/complete buttons it alerts me, so I know that they are working

this is my code so far and my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/fkhan698/pen/MLJYZZ?editors=1111) if that helps

```
var input = document.getElementById('userInput');
var enterButton = document.getElementById('enter');
var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("Remove");
for (var i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
  deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', deleteListItem, false);
}

var completeButtons =
  document.getElementsByClassName("Complete");
for (var i = 0; i < completeButtons.length; i++) {
  completeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', completeListItem, false);
}
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
};

function listLength() {
  return item.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  //makes text node 

  var clonedButton =
    document.getElementById("buttons").cloneNode(true);
  clonedButton.childNodes[1].addEventListener('click', deleteListItem, false);
  clonedButton.childNodes[3].addEventListener('click', completeListItem, false);

  li.appendChild(clonedButton);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";

}

function deleteListItem() {
  alert("Yuh");
  // li.classList.add("delete");
}

function completeListItem() {
  alert("Item was completed");
  li.classLi

}

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}
// Hit enter key and create list
function addAfterPress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.which === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

enterButton.addEventListener('click', addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener('keypress', addAfterPress);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `li` is the grandparent node of the delete and complete buttons (the parent is the clone of `buttons`). So you want:

```
function deleteListItem() {
  var li = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  li.remove();
}

function completeListItem() {
  var li = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  li.classList.add("Complete");
}
```